# C# - Object variable assignment failing

Tags: c#, variables, variable-assignment

I'm having some trouble understanding why my variable has a null value.

Here's my class constructor:

```
private GraphNode current;
private GraphNode goal;
private GraphNode start;

private List<GraphNode> path;
private List<GraphNode> origin;

public Graph()
{
    current = new GraphNode(0, 0);
    goal = new GraphNode(0, 0);
    start = new GraphNode(0, 0);
    path = new List<GraphNode>();
    origin = new List<GraphNode>();
}
```

Defenition of method SetPathing:

```
public void SetPathing(int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    if (Contains((int)mouseX / 32, (int)mouseY / 32))
    {
        goal = GetNode((int)mouseX / 32, (int)mouseY / 32);
        current = goal;
        path.Add(current);

        while ((current.X != start.X) && (current.X != start.X))
        {
            current = origin.Where(keyValuePair => (keyValuePair.Key.X == current.X) && (keyValuePair.Key.X == current.Y)).Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value).LastOrDefault();
            path.Add(current);
        }
    }
}
```

When I break on the start of the while-loop in SetPathing I see the following info in the locals screen:

```
current     null                    PathFinding.GraphNode
goal        {PathFinding.GraphNode} PathFinding.GraphNode
        X   0   int
        x   0   int
        Y   5   int
        y   5   int
```

How is that possible after having clearly assigned the reference value of **goal** to **current**?

I'm probably missing something stupid here, but I haven't found it after looking for two hours. No asynchronous going on here.

**EDIT**: Didn't want to be overtly verbose with my initial question, here's some extra details, my apologies. Here are the details of Contains, GetNode and GetNodeIndex. Nothing fancy, I'm an amateur.

```
    public int GetNodeIndex(int x, int y)
    {
        // Find the node index in the list based on x and y
        // Return -1 if not found
        return nodes.FindIndex(n => (n.X == x) && (n.Y == y));
    }

    public GraphNode GetNode(int x, int y)
    {
        // Find the node in the list based on x and y
        // Return null if not in list
        int nodeIndex = GetNodeIndex(x, y);
        if (nodeIndex != -1)
        {
            return nodes[nodeIndex];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public bool Contains(int x, int y)
    {
        // Check if the returned value is not -1
        if (GetNodeIndex(x, y) != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The usecase is litterally just along the lines of the following:

```
using System;

namespace Graphs
{
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Graph graph = new Graph(20, 20);
            graph.SetPathing(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. In particular, it depends on the return value of `GetNode`... my guess is that *that's* returning `null`.

Comment: I cant see anything that would cause that. What I would recommend is stepping through your code from the top of SetPathing, checking your watches along the way. At the first path.Add, current cannot be null if goal isnt null.

Comment: Can we see definitions of `Contains()` and `GetNode()`?

Comment: Why do you cast `mouseX` and `mouseY` to `int` when they are already `int`?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `current = goal`.  when you hit that breakpoint, look in your toolbars for some curved arrow buttons called:  `Step Into`, `Step Over`, and `Step Out`.  Use `Step Into` button, and see where that takes you

Comment: Do you have _local_ variables `current` etc. that **hide** the _fields_ (class-level variables) `current` etc. because they have identical names?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen
That is a very good question to which I have no proper answer. Just me being confused after a couple of hours of working with SFML, which uses a bunch of Vectors with float values. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Wait, is it `ShowPathing` or `SetPathing`? And also, what is `path`? Where is `origin` defined? Are `goal` and `current` used anywhere apart from that single method? (and if not, why don't you make them local variables instead?) As Jon has already commented above, please provide a complete working example which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Groo - Sorry for the methods names, my mistake. Path is indeed relevant: it's a List<GraphNode>, added that to description. Origin is also a List<GraphNode>, but it is irrelevant to this question. Yes, they are accessed elsewhere, but not in an asynchronous way.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen No, no other local variables defined in the method. You're looking at the complete method.

Comment: @RobinMattheussen OK, so given that `current` etc. are not local variables, I assume you had expanded the `this` node in your *Locals* window?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen Correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is possible, but the answer appears to be that this is in fact not the first iteration of the While-loop.

I had my break point set to the loop, and the results I posted above were from the first hit of that break point. However, after adding a variable that acted as an iteration counter it turned out this was in fact NOT the first iteration, but the third one. Following this discovery I went on to improve the code in the while loop to prevent current being set to null.

I'm not sure how this could happen. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop. Never encountered anything like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Let's dissect your code here.

`goal = GetNode((int)mouseX / 32, (int)mouseY / 32);`

Here, you've set the variable goal to point to a GraphNode object. So, for the sake of simplicity, we'll call it A. At this point your values look like this:

```
goal -> A
current -> null
```

Next, you do this:

```
current = goal;
```

And now, your values look like this:

```
goal -> A
current -> A
```

Later during your while loop, you call this:

```
current = origin.Where(keyValuePair => (keyValuePair.Key.X == current.X) && (keyValuePair.Key.X == current.Y)).Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value).LastOrDefault();
```

For the sake of simplicity, we'll call the result of this where clause B. So, now your values look like this:

```
goal -> A
current -> B
```

All that you have done here is change `current` to point to a new value.

Comment: He's breaking before the while loop.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't realize that this break point was before even the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You showed the code for the default Graph constructor,

```
public Graph()
```

not the one being used.

```
Graph graph = new Graph(20, 20);
```

Is there any difference between them?

Also, are you sure your code is in sync with the assembly? i.e. from your description it seems your break point is on this line

```
while ((current.X != start.X) && (current.X != start.X))
```

Are you sure when you were debugging, it was indeed executing only upto here when the debugger stopped, or it could have already executed the filtering code two lines down?